# Factoring A 4th DegreePolynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am trying to factor by hand $$ 3k^4+7k^2+2 $$ to $$ (3k^2+1)(k^2+2) $$ but I have no idea how to even start.Is there any way without using the quartic formula in this case?

Comment: Do you know how to factor $3h^{2}+7h+2$? If so you can just put $h=k^{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x^2=y$, then $$3y^2+7y+2=0 \implies y=-2, -1/3 \implies 3y^2-7y+2=(y+2)~(3y+1).$$ Hence
$$3x^4+7x^2+2=(x^2+2)(3x^2+1)$$

Comment: Why $y^2-7y+2$ can be factorised

Comment: Oh! it was a typo it should be $3y^2-7y+2=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just did it. That polynomial factors just by hand because it’s pretty plain and simple. You don’t actually need to make a substitution $u = k^2$ if you can do it by inspection.